# Sonarqube 6.4+: Can't change permission to private project

Tags: sonarqube

We have an on-prem installation of Sonarqube, on a server that has no connection to the internet, just internal network.

With the introduction of private/public I have the need to make all projects (100+) private since we can't allow everyone to read code from all projects. But right now I can't even change it to private on any project. Right now it looks like this:

[image: Sonarqube permission box]

The option private is greyed out and not clickable. Any suggestions what to fix to make this option available?

(Also the "billing box" seems like a bug where the server expects a internet connection to serve the content.)

The issue exist on both 6.4 and 6.5.

UPDATE:
My list of plugins:

```
sonar-csharp-plugin-5.9.0.1001
sonar-javascript-plugin-2.21.0.4409
sonar-ldap-plugin-2.1.0.507
sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2
sonar-spcaf-plugin
```

And my `sonar.properties` if that is interesting (censored):

```
## Logging sonar

.log.level=DEBUG

## Database configuration
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarservice
sonar.jdbc.password=***
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sonarqube

## Web configuration
sonar.web.port=9000
sonar.web.sso.enable=true

# LDAP configuration
# General Configuration
sonar.authenticator.downcase=true
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://***
ldap.realm=***

ldap.bindDn=***
ldap.bindPassword=***

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=***
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=displayName
ldap.user.emailAttribute=userPrincipalName

# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=***
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
ldap.group.idAttribute=sAMAccountName
```

Comment: That's definitely an issue. When you open a page, there is an API call to /api/navigation/component. Could you tell me if the "configuration" field is present, and if the "canUpdateProjectVisibilityToPrivate" is "true"?

Comment: Configuration field is there and the boolean is set to false

Comment: Could you please send the list of plugins you've installed ?

Comment: I've added it to the question above. Also included my properties list, otherwise it is a default installation.

(The plugins may not be the latest, but updated within the last 2-3 months at least)

Comment: What is the sonar-spcaf-plugin ? Could you try without this plugin ?

Comment: Its a 3rd party Sharepoint scanning plugin that we were testing. I disabled that, no change. Then I disabled all plugins except the ldap plugin and no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this in the following constellation:

- User is a member of an administrator group (not sonar-administrators).
- This admin group does not have the "Project administer" permission on the project
- Go via Global Administration -> Projects -> Management -> Edit Permissions
- The radio button for private is disabled

This is a nasty bug, but I found a workaround after examining the Web-API. I saw that the "api/projects/update_visibility" requires 'Project administer' permission on the specified project or view"

**Workaround**: Add your admin group for this project with the "Administer" permission, then reload the page. The radiobutton should now be visible.

Comment: Of course that was the problem, I was logged in as a user that I had given administrator rights to Sonarqube but not sonar-administrators. I actually redid the entire installation 
(from an old database) and that solved the problem, but that was probably because I now added that user to sonar-administrators.